# VB.net BackgroundWorker UI

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I am trying to create an app that produces an excel document based on user input. The document can become quite extensive (multiple sheets), so I want to put the creation of the document on a BackgroundWorker and pass the progress to a ProgressBar.

I'm having problems accessing UI controls while creating the document.
How can I access multiple UI controls from a BackgroundWorker?

This is a very basic example of two of the many things that i want to do in the BackgroundWorker:

```
 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    OpenWorkbook()

    Dim Combobox() As ComboBox = {ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3, ComboBox4}

    With xlWorkBook.Sheets("Cover1")
        .Range("E5").Value = TextBox1.Text
        .Range("E6").Value = TextBox2.Text
        .Range("E7").Value = TextBox3.Text
        .Range("E8").Value = TextBox4.Text

        For i = 0 To Combobox.Count - 1
            .Range("A" & i + 1).Value = Combobox(i).Text
        Next
    End With

    CloseWorkBook()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

I'm not experienced at all and after researching on this subject, I'm still not getting along with the Delegate/Invoke. Any help would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is going on in `OpenWorkbook` and `CloseWorkBook`

Comment: You need the controls' values in `DoWork`, not the controls themselves. A [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync) overload lets you pass an object, which becomes the `Arguments` of [DoWorkEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs). You can pass to the `DoWork` method all the values you need using this object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Heinzi you cant just pass reference to a control into a bgw. instead you pass the values.

```
             Option Strict On
            Public Class FormControls
                WithEvents Bgw As New ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker With {.WorkerReportsProgress = True}

                Public Class BgwArgs
                    Public TxtBx1Txt As String = FormControls.TextBox1.Text
                    Public TxtBx2Txt As String = FormControls.TextBox2.Text
                    Public CmbBx1Txt As String = FormControls.ComboBox1.SelectedText
                End Class

                Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
                    Dim BgwArgs As New BgwArgs
                    Bgw.RunWorkerAsync(BgwArgs)
                End Sub

                Private Sub Bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles Bgw.DoWork
                    Dim BgwArgs As BgwArgs = DirectCast(e.Argument, BgwArgs)

                    .Range("E5").Value = BgwArgs.TxtBx1Txt 'etc

                End Sub

            End Class
```

I assume the `OpenWorkbook` is a sub that uses interop to create `xlWorkBook` where you would instead want to do that within the thread also, same with `CloseWorkbook` all that should be handled in the DoWork event and not in their own separate routines.

Comment: That's the correct approach, but there are some details wrong: You should *not* pass references to the UI controls (which will cause the same problem as the one the OP is having), but rather pass the **value** contained in those controls (i.e., `BgwArgs` should contain `TxtBx1Text`, not `TxtBx1`).

Comment: Its working! I will have to re-arrange most of my code but thats not a problem. I guess I should grab a vb.net book someday when the time allows... Thanks a lot.